sum for each category in factor variables
I would like to get a table that counts the frequencies of each factor category across all variables except id. I have a number of variables that each can contain 1, 0 or NA, and I want a table that gives me the frequency of each of those. Below I have changed NA to 2 because NA is not included as a category in factor variables and then I make each of the variables except id factors. I can't figure out the final step to get the table in 'want' below that simply counts for each variable how many 1s, how many 0s and how many NAs.
# have
df3=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               ibd=c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
               ihd=c(1,1,0,NA,0,0,1),
               psoriasis=c(0,0,NA,0,0,1,1),
               mi=c(1,0,0,0,0,NA,1)
)

df3 %>% replace(is.na(.), 2)

df3 <- df3 %>%
  mutate(across(-c(id), as.factor))

# want
df5=data.frame(id=c("1s", "0s", "NAs"),
               ibd=c(4,3,0),
               ihd=c(3,3,1),
               psoriasis=c(2,4,1),
               mi=c(2,4,1)
)


library(tidyr); library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(df3, -id) |>
  group_by(name) |>
  count(value) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from=n, values_fill=0)

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  value   ibd   ihd    mi psoriasis
  <fct> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
1 0         3     3     4         4
2 1         4     3     2         2
3 NA        0     1     1         1


group_by(name) |> count(value) is equal to count(name, value)

You can use table + stack like below
table(
  stack(
    type.convert(df3[-1], as.is = TRUE)
  ),
  useNA = "ifany"
)

which gives
      ind
values ibd ihd psoriasis mi
  0      3   3         4  4
  1      4   3         2  2
  <NA>   0   1         1  1


Filter(is.factor, df3) |>
  lapply(\(x) table(factor(x, levels = c(1, 0)), useNA = "always")) |>
  do.call(cbind, args = _) |>
  as_tibble(rownames = "id")

#   id      ibd   ihd psoriasis    mi
#   <chr> <int> <int>     <int> <int>
# 1 1         4     3         2     2
# 2 0         3     3         4     4
# 3 NA        0     1         1     1

Where
df3 <- data.frame(
  id = seq(1, 7, by = 1),
  ibd = factor(c("0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1")),
  ihd = factor(c("1", "1", "0", NA, "0", "0", "1")),
  psoriasis = factor(c("0", "0", NA, "0", "0", "1", "1")),
  mi = factor(c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, "1"))
)


library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

select(df3, -id) |> 
  imap(\(x, y) as.data.frame(table(x, useNA = "always", dnn = "id"), responseName = y)) |> 
  reduce(full_join, by = "id")
#     id ibd ihd psoriasis mi
# 1    0   3   3         4  4
# 2    1   4   3         2  2
# 3 <NA>   0   1         1  1

